# Safely return pointer to member of local object

Tags: c++, memory, return, arduino

I write program for Arduino device, but question is general (I think).

Let's say I have following code:

```
char* ClassB::generateUrl()
{
    char* someString = (char*) malloc(...);
    // something...
    return someString;
}

char* ClassA::getMyUrl()
{
    ClassB b;
    return b.generateUrl();
}

void developerMethod()
{
    ClassA a;
    char* url = a.getMyUrl();
    print(url);
}
```

In this case developer who uses `ClassA::getMyUrl` must remember to free memory allocated for url. Is there any more user-friendly way to do it?
**Important**: due to memory limitations on Arduino board I don't want to return whole `ObjectB`, only what it has generated. And because it may be long string, I don't want to copy it to any buffer provided in `getMyUrl` method as argument.

**Update:**

I must've been not clear enough :). What I want to achieve:

- When returning from a.getMyUrl() I don't want to have `ClassB b` in memory
- When returning from developerMethod I don't want to have neither `ClassA a` nor  `char* url` in memory, without freeing.
- Possibly use char* over String

I know that using malloc is wrong here, that is why I asked this question, to probably get rid of malloc and have "automatic" (at least from the point of view of developer writing `developerMethod`) memory management.

I guess it might be difficult/impossible to achieve, but even if it is impossible, just let me know and I'll accept such answer (if anybody confirms or no other answers appear in a few days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
 class ClassB
 {
 public:

    ClassB()
    {
        strcpy(_someString, "my_url");
    }

    void generateUrl(char *url)
    {
        strcpy(url, _someString);

        //char* someString = (char*) malloc(...);
        // something...
        //return someString;
    }
private:
    char _someString[80];
};

class ClassA{
public:
    void getMyUrl(char *url)
    {
        ClassB b;
        b.generateUrl(url);
        //return b.generateUrl();
    }
};

void developerMethod()
{
    ClassA a;
    //char* url = a.getMyUrl();
    char url[80];
    a.getMyUrl(url);
    print(url);
}
```

Essentially you have to understand that you need to use strcpy, to move the content of the char-pointer from the interior memory of your class to the developerMethod(). By doing so, you can then delete all other class references and their memory because you are now independent of that memory. That approach is already outlined in my first answer, but now you have it all the way to the "top" call. I'm happy to explain more, but I'm getting to the point where it becomes difficult to find more to explain.

Comment: But then, I need to know in `developerMethod` expected size of this url... That's what I was afraid of and wanted to avoid as well (that's what I meant as "automatic memory management"). But I'll accept your solution as the most accurate to my problem.

Comment: use strncpy() notice the "n" and maybe get strlen() involved to "protect yourself".

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use strings in C++ simply use `std::string`. You don't have to bother about anything like this once you do that.
And this is precisely the reason C++ has `std::string`.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the Arduino C++ library doesn't have things such as `std::string`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There is a [String](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually, it has something like this, [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) is doc. I'll see if it helps.

Comment: Well, how should it actually solve my memory problem? If this string is private member, and `b` gets destroyed on exit from `getMyUrl` then this string will also be destroyed, won't it?

Comment: @AdamPierzchała: You simply change your interface from: `char* ClassA::getMyUrl()` to `std::string ClassA::getMyUrl()`, You return the string by value so the caller receives a copy and no one has to bother freeing anything.

Comment: Any other ideas? I would rather not use String class. [Here](http://miscsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/five-things-i-never-use-in-arduino-projects/) is why.

Comment: @AdamPierzchała: I am not qualified enough in Arduino to comment on whether using the String class is advisable or not. But this is the way you do it in C++.

Comment: err.. smart pointers? Like boost::scoped_array. But you can probably just write it on your own.

Comment: @AdamPierzchała you don't want to use String because of dynamic memory allocation, but you use malloc ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
class ClassB {
public:
    void setUrl(char *url){strncpy(url_, url, 80);}
    char *getUrl(char *url){return url_;}
private:
    char[80] url_; 
};

class ClassA 
{ 
public:
   char *getUrl(){return classB.getUrl();}
private:
    ClassB classB; 
};

ClassA classA;

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{
    char *url = classA.getUrl();
    Serial.println(url);
    delay(1000);
}
```

If this doesn't do the trick for you, please give us more detail of what you are trying to achieve that is not covered by this code example. Why a class in a class? Why use malloc? ...